# Missing JSON field on Instagram API

Tags: json, instagram

I want to use instagram API for getting full names of the people that posted comments on the posts.
I found this on instagram API documentations:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

{
    "data": [
        {
            "created_time": "1280780324",
            "text": "Really amazing photo!",
            "from": {
                "username": "snoopdogg",
                "profile_picture": "http://images.instagram.com/profiles/profile_16_75sq_1305612434.jpg",
                "id": "1574083",
                "full_name": "Snoop Dogg"
            },
            "id": "420"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to get `"full_name": "Snoop Dogg"`
But, maybe Im doing something wrong, or instagram stopped this function, but I cant get JSON file that has `'full_name'` field. 
I have tried with a lot of different post ids and access tokens but there is not `full_name`.

Is there any other way to get full name of the person that commented on some post?

This is my api link to the post that has more than 100 comments:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/2048769023904168265/comments?access_token=XXYYZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram API is being deprecated, and replaced by a new Graph API ([source](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)).

The endpoint you mention seems to be deprecated already:

> April 4, 2018
>
> The following endpoints are deprecated immediately:
>
> [...]
>
> - Commenting on Public Content
>
> ```
> GET /media/{media-id}/comments (Deprecation not relevant when fetching
> comments for self media)
> ```

Source: Instagram API changelog.

You may still get the full `from` object for your own comments.

I recommend switching to the new API, documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

Comment: Is there a way to get full_name of the users that posted comments?

Comment: not with the API you're using. For the new one, read the docs.